# Back to the gym after ilness

Tags: recovery, illness

I was ill, a flu, or other infection. I know that I had to suspend training sessions. This time it was 2 weeks, so nothing really special. It happens to me from time to time, and usually 2-3 weeks are lost. Then it takes another 2-4 weeks to get back to the weights I had before suspension.

My plan on getting back is - as follows:

First training. I'm doing half of weights - just to find out if everything is OK. I learned it can happen that I feel well, but my body is still ill. So I start with something small, and then get with higher. At each training, somewhere in the middle I test if a higher weight is not a problem - in the beginning higher means +20%. If that works then, next training means +10%. Usually that is too much. Also usually, a single set is not a problem, but whole training is different story.

My question is quite simple. Can I do it better? Can I recover faster? Maybe it is better to go with "normal" weight, and do less is better then slowly going up? Please share your ideas, tips, experience. Every answer is welcome!

Comment: Simplie answer is - not really. Thats how recovery goes. As an advice - better do fullbody training when you on your recovery, if you didn't already, this way it goes little faster

Comment: I think that's pretty normal and I think you're being pretty smart about it. This is response is definitely more a comment than an answer, but especially the first week (which it sounds like you're doing) your ego is put on the shelf for a bit and you muscle through the indignity of 1/2 your weights.

Answer (score 3):

Fitness is a marathon not a sprint.  Honestly your plan sounds perfect.  Feel things out and increase as you feel ready.

*Why rush anything?*  **Listen to your body and stick with your plan -- it's a good one.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with choosing to go less weight, and potentially then add more reps.  And then you could set your workout routine to factor in a progressive overload of the weight in your sets as the weeks go on...